# there any 2 ways to read all service bus messages from azure function HTTP trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

there are 2 ways to `read all the messages` from `service bus topic`.

`which one is recommended for azure functions`

option 1 -

```
var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(SBConnString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
Message message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
```

option 2 -

```
static async Task ReceiveOrProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
        // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

        // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the queueClient has already been closed.
        // If queueClient has already been Closed, you may chose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc. calls 
       // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
    }
```

what should be used for azure functions http trigger ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the azure [binding table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings), you could find azure function doesn't support service bus input binding for now.

So if you want to receive messages in the function, you could only use the service bus trigger or the service bus sdk. The first sample you provide is the sdk and the second is the trigger.

And you said you want to receive messages in the http trigger function, so you have to use the Service Bus SDK to implement. You could refer to the below code.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async void Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("servicebuscon");
            var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, "myqueue", ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null, 500);


            var tempMessages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            foreach (Message m1 in tempMessages)
            {

                log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m1.Body)}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: still not working could you please reply me why it is not working second time ? to reproduce issue run the same code http trigger function app locally hit localhost url see debugger first time it will read all the messages now send new messages to topic and hit loclahost url again ... u can observe second time though we have messages into topic but into code we have null messages at tempMessages why ?

Answer (score 1):

With reference to George Chen's code, you need to make a few changes in order to read all the messages from the Topic.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async void Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("servicebuscon");
        var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, "myqueue", ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null, 500);

        do
        {
        var tempMessages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        foreach (Message m1 in tempMessages)
        {

            log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m1.Body)}");
        }
        }while(tempMessages!=null);
    }
}
```

The above code has been modified with a do-while loop that receives all the messages from the Topic rather than the first messages in the queue.